# Cant access an image in a folder SAILS Js

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, sails.js

Now I am working in a half completed project built using angular js and Sails js. In this,recently the profile pics are stored in the folder ../asstes/images/profilepics/.. .jpg. Now I created a new folder called 'Thumb' inside the profilepics folder with the thumbnails of image in profilepics folder.So in the project, Now I am taking images from Thumb folder.But is is not get accessed. When I take inspect element from my web page I got the link as

```
http://192.168.1.75:9002/images/profilePics/Thumb/46323c0b-c75a-431e-9bff-c1f61de0bcb5.jpg
```

But not dispalying the image. I copied this link to browser, browser shows  error 404. why it happens so?.Any permission issue or something like that?.If I take pic directly from profile pics, it works fine. plzz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but a adress can not be http://192.168.example.something:numbers/youknow/

Comment: Thanks. I have checked, the address it is ok. But when I log out and again logged in it works fine

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you have to `sails lift` again so you new images and folders become available to Sails. @sulu666